# Would I notice any difference from restart Windows via cmd and restart via Windows GUI?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shutdown, reboot

I remote desktop my server computer a lot and I often use cmd to restart or shutdown the computer when it's needed. When in remote desktop you aren't allowed the option to restart unless you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> which can sometimes be a pain when I'm using my bluetooth keyboard. I'm not sure if this is considered a proper way to shutdown a computer or not even though it is a Windows command.

Is this method in anyway detrimental to the computer hardware or software on the to restart in this fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, both methods just do the same,** they turn off programs, GUI's, services and devices, leading your system into a safe shutdown.

The only turn-off method that would damage your computer is the "finger-off", where you turn off your system by removing it's power source abruptly.